# Open Activity with onChildclick

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener, expandablelistview

Basically, I'm trying to open an activity while clicking a child on an `expandableListView`, but can't get it done. Tried a lot of solutions (mainly, changing the arguments of the intent) to no avail.

These are my classes:

main_Magic

```
package com.arrowny.exalted;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class main_Magic extends AppCompatActivity {

  TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
  Typeface tf1, tf2;

  private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
  private List<String> headersList;
  private int lastPosition = -1;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_magic);

    tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Chapter.ttf");
    tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Titles.ttf");

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chapter);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.footer);

    tv1.setTypeface(tf1);
    tv2.setTypeface(tf1);
    tv3.setTypeface(tf2);

    headersList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] headers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.magic);
    List<String> parentHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(headers));
    headersList.addAll(parentHeaders);

    HashMap<String, List<String>> allChildItems = returnGroupedChildItems();
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    final ExpandableListViewAdapter expandableListViewAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), headersList, allChildItems);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListViewAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if (lastPosition != -1 && groupPosition != lastPosition) {
          expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastPosition);
        }
        lastPosition = groupPosition;
      }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        if (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 0) {
          Intent solar = new Intent(v.getContext(), charm_Solar.class); //This line is where I want to open the new Activity. Currently it stops the application while running it.
          startActivity(solar);
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  private HashMap<String, List<String>> returnGroupedChildItems() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> childContent = new HashMap<>();
    int size = headersList.size();
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
      List<String> childList = new ArrayList<>();

      if (i == 1) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.exalted);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 2) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.martialArts);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 3) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.knacks);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 4) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.astrology);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 5) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sorcery);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 6) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.necromancy);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 7) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.protocols);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 8) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arcanoi);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 9) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.thaumaturgy);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 10) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.patterns);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      } else if (i == 11) {
        String[] child = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paths);
        List<String> childHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child));
        childList.addAll(childHeaders);
      }
      childContent.put(headersList.get(i - 1), childList);
    }
    return childContent;
  }
}
```

And this is my adapter:

ExpandableListViewAdapter

```
package com.arrowny.exalted;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

  private Context context;
  private List<String> parentDataSource;
  private HashMap<String, List<String>> childDataSource;

  public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> childParent, HashMap<String, List<String>> child) {
    this.context = context;
    this.parentDataSource = childParent;
    this.childDataSource = child;
  }

  @Override
  public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.parentDataSource.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.childDataSource.get(this.parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return parentDataSource.get(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.childDataSource.get(parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);
    }

    String parentHeader = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    TextView parentItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    parentItem.setText(parentHeader);

    Typeface parentFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Titles.ttf");
    parentItem.setTypeface(parentFont, Typeface.BOLD);

    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
    }

    String childName = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    TextView childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
    childItem.setText(childName);

    Typeface childFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Titles.ttf");
    childItem.setTypeface(childFont);

    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me out on this.

Comment: Just to give some extra info. While trying to get the intent, the App restarts. This happen on runtime, no error is found when compiling it.

Also, when using Toast to display messages, it works just fine.

Some of the arguments I have tried are the following:

Intent (v.getContext(), charm_Solar.class)
Intent (main_Magic.this, charm_Solar.class)
Intent (this, charm_Solar.class)


The first two compile right, the last one isn't accepted.

Comment: Can you please post the logcat shown when the application closes?